# Checking if object has custom attribute

Tags: vb.net, object, reflection, custom-attributes, deep-copy

I've got a recursive deep-copy function to create new instances of objects. To improve my function's capabilities I want to put some kind of `<noCopy>` custom attribute on some values within my object to prevent them from beeing copied

an object to be copied may look like this:

```
public Class CDatabase
    public var1 as double
    private var2 as CSomeObject
    <noCopy> private var3 as double
    <noCopy> private var4 as CSomeObject
    ...
end class
```

my recursive function looks like this:

```
public shared Function Copy(originalObject as Object) as Object

    if originalObject = nothing then
         return nothing
    end if

    if Attribute.IsDefined(originalObject.GetType, GetType(NoCopy)) 'This does not work
         return nothing
    end if 

    ~ do other recursive stuff ~

    return cloned object
end function
```

my attribute is defined as followed:

```
<System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.All)>
 Public Class NoCopy
    Inherits System.Attribute
 End Class
```

and I call my clone function like that:

```
public Class Example

    dim original as Database
    dim clone as Database
    clone = original.Copy

    'This one returns true
    Dim test As Boolean = Attribute.IsDefined(original.GetType.GetMember("var3")(0), GetType(NoCopy))  

end class
```

when I try to get the attributes of `originalObject` I always get a false return value. But when I do it by referring directly to the object I get a positive result.

Comment: `AutoMapper` handles this kind of thing.

Comment: if you apply `NoCopy` to fields, checking the type (class) for the attribute wont work.

Comment: As I said, the copy function works recursively. It gets an `object_1` and passes any objects contained in `object_1` into itself until it hits on primitive types, which can't be broken down into smaller pieces. Each time the passed object is checked for ist Attribute.

Comment: still, if you want to find the attribute on the Type, you need to apply it to the Type.  The sample class does not have the attribute on the class itself, so the code marked `does not work` is correct: the `CDatabase` Type doesnt have that attribute applied.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see the forest for the trees. How do I have to access my objects inside my copy function to get their attributes? Every page I find on Google or MSDN only tells me how I can check for members/properties inside of other objects. I'm really stuck on this :-/

Comment: First, I think you have Recursion confused with Reflection.  Your code does not recurse.  I am not sure why you think you need reflection - if you do not want to set this or that member, dont set it.  The only reason it might be needed is to set a private field but all those are NoCopy

Comment: Nope, it's recursive. I just reduced my code to the relevant sections. I'm using methods very similar to Alexey Burtsev's Deep Copy method to copy my objects: https://github.com/Burtsev-Alexey/net-object-deep-copy/blob/master/ObjectExtensions.cs

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer:
you cannot check an object for its attributes directly, but you have to do so by asking its parent object. 
Thank god I'm using a recursive function. Instead of checking my objects for having an attribute AFTER it has been passed into the next recursion, I have to check, before it gets passed further:

```
function Copy (originalObject as Object)

    ' do stuff

   for each myFieldInfo as FieldInfo in CType(originalObject.[GetType], Type).GetFields
       If Not Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fieldInfo, GetType(NoCopy)) Is Nothing Then
            'set value to nothing
       End If

       ' do more stuff
       ' call self with field of originalObject
    next
end function
```

If anyone's interested in the modified function of Alexey's method, replace `sub copyField` with the following:

```
    Private Sub CopyFields(originalObject As Object, visited As IDictionary(Of Object, Object), cloneObject As Object, typeToReflect As Type, _
                       Optional bindingFlags__1 As BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.[Public] Or _
                       BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy, Optional filter As Func(Of FieldInfo, Boolean) = Nothing)
    For Each fieldInfo As FieldInfo In typeToReflect.GetFields(bindingFlags__1)
        If filter IsNot Nothing AndAlso filter(fieldInfo) = False Then
            Continue For
        End If

        If IsPrimitive(fieldInfo.FieldType) AndAlso (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fieldInfo, GetType(NoCopy)) Is Nothing) Then
            Continue For
        End If
        Dim originalFieldValue As Object = fieldInfo.GetValue(originalObject)
        If Not Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fieldInfo, GetType(NoCopy)) Is Nothing Then
            fieldInfo.SetValue(cloneObject, Nothing)
        Else
            Dim clonedFieldValue As Object = InternalCopy(originalFieldValue, visited)
            fieldInfo.SetValue(cloneObject, clonedFieldValue)
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help Plutonix, nonetheless